# Token for different content?

Tags: tokens

I have created a template that I am going to send to a group of people. Depending on a certain value (in this case a custom field), I want to use a different picture.

Today I create four different templates.

Is there a way to "merge" content in a template based on another field value?

And is it a generic way of doing this, if I next time want to merge different sentences, based on the same field values I used for the pictures?

(I have looked at the extension [Content Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/content-tokens), but this is slightly different)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had success in differentiating content based on the value of a custom field by enabling Smarty for message templates http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC46/Smarty+in+mail+templates

Answer (score 0):

You can code an extension to provide custom tokens using [hook_civicrm_tokens](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_tokens) and [hook_civicrm_tokenValues](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_tokenValues).